# Scala - how to not call a unary method

Tags: scala, methods, unary-operator

I have this code:

```
def +(s: String) = s.headOption

val foo = +("hello")
```

When trying to compile it , I get a compiler error:

```
Error: value unary_+ is not a member of String
    val foo = +("hello")
```

How can I prevent the compiler from inserting a call to `String.unary_-`, but instead call the method in scope?

Comment: There's an issue for why is it necessary to `this.f(arg)` to get implicit conversion on `this` (converting it to something with `f`), why isn't `f(arg)` enough. This might be a good example why not. Or, maybe they are both an argument to try `this.expr` before failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val foo = this.+("hello") //this will call the class, object etc. and you will get the correct reference for the method :)
```

Or:

```
import <path>._

val foo = classname.+("hello")
```

Or:

```
import <path>.<class>

val foo = <class>.+("hello")
```

Ex:

```
package test

object SO {

  def +(s:String) = s.headOption

}

package test

object add extends App {
  import test.SO

  println(SO.+("hello"))
}
```

Res:

```
Some(h)
```

Ex2:

```
package test

class SO {}
object SO {
    def apply(): SO = {
        new SO
    }
    def +(s:String) = s.headOption
}



package test

object add extends App {
  import test.SO

  println(SO.+("string"))
}
```

Res:

```
 Some(s)
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @corvus_192 yes it does

Comment: @Johnny It compiles, but it only works with Strings, because it's equivalent to `this.toString + "hello"`. [Test it](https://ideone.com/JfDhfi)

Comment: @corvus_192
If my solutions was equivalent to `this.toString + "hello"` the result would be "test.SO$@5cad8086hello". That's not the case. The result is Some(h). Try the code before commenting please.

Comment: @corvus_192 Your linked code doesn't do what you think. `this.ident` does not refer to imported `ident`. You can see evil `any2stringadd` at work using `-Xprint:typer`.

Comment: @Jonny if by "works" you mean "compiles", than yes. If you mean does what the OP wanted, then no. Your original answer that is, the first version. The second one kinda does, but that's not quite what was asked.

Comment: @Dima well the thing is, you can't. Unless you override the main +(s: string) method or remove the package which contains the original +(s: string) method. The op asked how to prevent it from calling unary_, my code prevents it.

Comment: @Johnny So is there any chance to call the imported method if I don't know where I imported it from, and which works with types other than String?

Comment: @corvus_192 No, in case it's included in the standard scala library, and you don't remove it. I think you could however define your own class and set it as input for your method ex: +(new Myclass ("string")). And you would define the method for your class, because it would not then conflict with scala librarys, but I'm not sure. You have to know where you import stuff from!

Comment: @Johnny I'm generating code from a programming language I'm developing, so I don't know where function come from.